# How to slide in divs from off screen into absolute layout using CSS transitions?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, margin

I have a grid of absolutely positioned divs (the grid is made up of differently shaped rectangles that fit together to make a large rectangle).

I am trying to animate the display of this grid by having all of the individual rectangles 'fly' into the grid from offscreen. So the rectangles on the left fly in from the left, the ones on the right from the right etc.

I am using CSS3 transitions and when flying in from the top or left it works perfectly, I just use negative margins to position them off screen and then animate this to change to margin-left (or margin-top) = 0 (e.g. the orignal/correct position).

This seems to make more sense than using transforms but please correct me if you think there is a reason that transforms will work/perform better for any reason?

However this obviously won't work for margin-right/margin-top and so i wanted to see if anyone can suggest what the best way to achieve this is from the right and bottom? I can make the parent overflow:hidden and animate the left/top positions which will have the same effect but I wanted to see if there's a generic solution equivalent to negative margins so as to prevent needing separate rules/positions for each off and on screen version? eg when using negative margins i can apply the same negative margin to all boxes that fly in from the same side without having any element specific mark up (but if i animate the top/left then each element will need it's own 'offscreen' position relative to it's final position so it flies in from the right place).

Alternatively if there is a better way in general (CSS3 is fine!) then I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't animate with margins, always animate with transforms, that is their intended use. Here is a great article on that from Paul Irish

Why moving elements with translate() is better
http://paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Use overflow-x: hidden to hide the divs coming in from the right. Here is a fiddle I made to show how you can animate with transform without specifying pixel values;

https://jsfiddle.net/P9GNS/3/

```js
$('.box-wrapper').each(function(index, element) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.remove('loading');
  }, index * 600);

});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.box-wrapper {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 600ms;
  transition-duration: 600ms;
}

.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(odd) {
  transform: translate(100%)
}

.box-wrapper.loading:nth-child(even) {
  transform: translate(-100%)
}

.box-wrapper:nth-child(odd) .box {
  background: orange
}

.box-wrapper:nth-child(even) .box {
  background: red
}

.box {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper loading">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Michael, that is perfect, my bad for not trying to use transforms first that makes much more sense and works exactly as needed. Thanks again!

Comment: just a follow up question, this works using 100% transform when the wrappers take up all available space but i'm trying to slide divs into another div which only takes up part of the viewport. This means if you use 100% it does not appear off screen (and i can't use overflow hidden on the container div otherwise they won't fly in from off screen). What is the optimum way to deal with this? I can obviously use transform 10000% or similar to ensure it's way offscreen (to allow for large displays) but this does not seem like the proper way to deal with it? Thanks!

Comment: You can specify a pixel value instead of a percentage. I would have to see it because it really depends on what it all looks like.

Comment: if you have a chance i've added another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434593/how-to-move-fluid-divs-the-correct-distance-on-off-screen-using-css3-transforms which gives an example of what i'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually `transform: translate...` gives you better performance on most of the browsers, because they try to render the animation using the GPU.

You can check those results from [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/translate3d-vs-xy/57).

Anyway another good solution ( without javascript ) would be to attach the animation entirely in CSS with `@keyframes` and `animation:` property.

More information on this issue is in [this article](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/).

From the guidelines you can read

> Use CSS keyframe animation or CSS transitions, if at all possible. The browser can optimize painting and compositing bigtime here.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply, although i'm lightly confused as the guidelines say "Use CSS keyframe animation or CSS transitions" but you say transform gives better performance? Presumably if i use keyframes or transform though i still have the same issue of having to animate the top/left positions and hence have to have set positions on and off screen for each rectangle (rather than a generic negative margin for multiple rectangles)? Maybe this is the only way but i wanted to see if there's a more general alternative? Thanks so much

Comment: I have tried to give you a fast jsbin with the desired effect http://jsbin.com/qozinoqu/1/

Comment: Thanks so much drinchev, that makes perfect sense and it's my fault for not trying with transforms first. I get it now! Thanks :)