# Is it possible to continuously animate a carousel of DIVs?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Assuming the red box represents my webpages container, and items B,C,D are outside the container. Is it possible to have the items (A,B,C,D...) auto scroll left to right like a carousel using just CSS?

I'm seen examples online on how to do this with images but not with DIVs full of text with a set width?

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  background: red;
  padding: 36px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 72px;
    margin-right: 72px;
    padding: 36px;  
position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    background: #efefef;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div> 
    <div class="item">D</div>    
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This link might be of help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309789/how-to-slide-in-divs-from-off-screen-into-absolute-layout-using-css-transitions

Comment: thanks but that's animating in which is easy... the challenge here is creating an infinite auto animating carousel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way to do it.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.items {
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  background: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: slide-item 4s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  opacity: 0;
}

.item:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 1s; }
.item:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 2s; }
.item:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 3s; }

@keyframes slide-item {
    0% { left: 150%; opacity: 1; }
   36% { left:  50%; opacity: 1; }
   72% { left: -50%; opacity: 1; }
  100% { left: -50%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but is there a way so they are not coming and going but more next to each other and in a loop

Comment: @AnApprentice, yes, there is. But I coded it just to show you it can be done, not so you could refine your request as we go. Play with timings yourself. Read documentations and web standards. (Re)search. From my POV, you should have come with an attempt yourself, before asking. Also, remember it's not a real carousel. Has no play/pause, there are no settings. It's just hardcoding some transitions so they appear to be a carousel. But a carousel means DOM manipulation. Which means: use JavaScript. That's what JS is for.

Comment: @AnApprentice, change `animation-timing-function` to `linear` and `width` to `60%` to achieve a *"conveyor belt"* effect type. You might also want to change the overall animation cycle duration and the delays based on page width, using `@media` queries.